# Angular - 2 way data binding rxjs subject property, never emits on the child, yet emits on the parent

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I have this custom child component in the template of a parent component:

parent html:

```
<cb-filter-chip-list [(filter-chips$)]="$ctrl.filterChips$"
                     [(filter-chip-adds)]="$ctrl.filterChipAdds"
                     [(filter-chip-deletes)]="$ctrl.filterChipDeletes"
                     [(current-chip-count)]="$ctrl.currentChipCount"
                     (update-data-behind-filter-chips)="$ctrl.updateDataBehindFilterChips($event)">
</cb-filter-chip-list>
```

parent ts:

```
public filterChips$ = new BehaviorSubject<Array<FilterChip>>(undefined);
public filterChipAdds = new ReplaySubject<any>(10);
public filterChipDeletes = new Subject();
```

child ts:

```
export class FilterChipListComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() public filterChips$: BehaviorSubject<Array<FilterChip>>;
    @Input() public filterChipAdds: BehaviorSubject<any>;
    @Input() public filterChipDeletes: Subject<any>;
    @Output() public updateDataBehindFilterChips = new EventEmitter<FilterChip[]>();
    createChip: Observable<any>;
    deleteChip: Observable<any>;
    chipVariations: Observable<unknown>;
    @Input() public currentChipCount: any;

    constructor() { }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.createChip = this.filterChipAdds.pipe(map(chip => ([{ ...chip, action: 'add' }])));
        this.deleteChip = this.filterChipDeletes.pipe(
            tap((chipId) => this.updateDataBehindFilterChips.emit(chipId)),
            map(chipId => ([{ id: chipId, action: 'delete' }])));
        this.chipVariations = merge(this.createChip, this.deleteChip);
        this.currentChipCount = this.chipVariations.pipe(
           // startWith(this.filterChips$.value),
            scan((totalCurrentChips: FilterChip[], changeInChips: ChipAction) => {
                if (changeInChips[0].action === 'add') {
                    if (totalCurrentChips.some(tcc => tcc.id === changeInChips[0].id)) {
                        totalCurrentChips.forEach(element => {
                            if (element.id === changeInChips[0].id) {
                                element.text = changeInChips[0].text;
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        totalCurrentChips.push(changeInChips[0]);
                    }
                } else if (changeInChips[0].action === 'delete') {
                    totalCurrentChips = totalCurrentChips.filter(chip => chip.id !== changeInChips[0].id);
                }
                return totalCurrentChips.sort((a, b) => a.sortOrder - b.sortOrder);
            })
        );

        // console.log(this.filterChipAdds);
        this.currentChipCount.subscribe();
        this.filterChipAdds.subscribe(x => console.log("fc", x));
    }
}
```

In the parent I make it emit by doing this:

```
this.filterChipAdds.next({
                id: "fromDate",
                sortOrder: 4,
                text: `From Date - ${this.datePipe.transform(this.userCacheItem.silentData.fromDate, "dd MMM yyyy")
                    }`
            });
```

For some reason the `this.filterChipAdds.subscribe(console.log);` on the parent console logs the values being emitted, but the `this.filterChipAdds.subscribe(x => console.log("fc", x));` doesn't log anything. nothing emits on the child. even though it should technically emit for both since it is a two way data binding. Why is the emission not mirrored on the child component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any issue with 2 way binding, it should work the way you are expecting i.e. the child component's subscribe should also gets triggered.

Now I actually took your code and try to run and it did work if I comment some of the lines and that makes me think that it won't work if you pass some undefined value from your parent. Because as soon as observable emits an error it will stop emitting new items, unless you have handle the errors correct which is not the case here.
Here is how I tired
In child component

```
@Input() public filterChips$: BehaviorSubject<Array<any>>;
    @Input() public filterChipAdds: BehaviorSubject<any>;
    @Input() public filterChipDeletes: Subject<any>;
    @Output() public updateDataBehindFilterChips = new EventEmitter<any[]>();
    createChip: Observable<any>;
    deleteChip: Observable<any>;
    chipVariations: Observable<unknown>;
    @Input() public currentChipCount: any;

    constructor() { }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        // this.createChip = this.filterChipAdds.pipe(map(chip => ([{ ...chip, action: 'add' }])));
        // this.deleteChip = this.filterChipDeletes.pipe(
        //     tap((chipId) => this.updateDataBehindFilterChips.emit(chipId)),
        //     map(chipId => ([{ id: chipId, action: 'delete' }])));
        // this.chipVariations = merge(this.createChip, this.deleteChip);
        // this.currentChipCount = this.chipVariations.pipe(
        //    // startWith(this.filterChips$.value),
        //     scan((totalCurrentChips: any[], changeInChips: any) => {
        //         if (changeInChips[0].action === 'add') {
        //             if (totalCurrentChips.some(tcc => tcc.id === changeInChips[0].id)) {
        //                 totalCurrentChips.forEach(element => {
        //                     if (element.id === changeInChips[0].id) {
        //                         element.text = changeInChips[0].text;
        //                     }
        //                 });
        //             } else {
        //                 totalCurrentChips.push(changeInChips[0]);
        //             }
        //         } else if (changeInChips[0].action === 'delete') {
        //             totalCurrentChips = totalCurrentChips.filter(chip => chip.id !== changeInChips[0].id);
        //         }
        //         return totalCurrentChips.sort((a, b) => a.sortOrder - b.sortOrder);
        //     })
        // );

        // console.log(this.filterChipAdds);
        // this.currentChipCount.subscribe();
        this.filterChipAdds.subscribe(x => console.log("fc", x));
    }
```

In parent component

```
filterChipAdds = new ReplaySubject<any>(10);

  click(){
    console.log('clicked');
    this.filterChipAdds.next('aaa');
  }
```

And just to test if its working created a button in parent component which will call the parent component's method which then set the value of observable.

```
<button (click)="click()">Click</button>
```

This is the output of the program after clicking on the button
[image: this is the output of the program after clicking on the button]

What I recommend is first try to comment out all the lines and just focus on `filterChipAdds` the way I did it in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4y7h3f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts). Once it starts showing you the result then one by one try to analyze the miss.

I hope you will track the down the issue this way.

Comment: I added the link which has the complete execution, do you still think its needed?

Comment: [Yes it is still required](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Thanks @NaveenMotwani-AIS I think you're right as it also worked for me when passing an initial value. The lesson here sounds like it is to use some error handling, so that an error won't stop execution of the following emissions.